# How to avoid being overwhelmed by the amount of frameworks and new versions of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frameworks, requirejs

First I learned HTML, CSS, JavaScript (es5, I believe I have a firm understanding of the foundation, like event loop, hoisting, closure, binding etc), then jQuery, PHP.

Then I started using frameworks. Built some pages with ReactJS (really liked the the uni-direction and dividing everything into components structure), built a restful API with Slim.

Then I realize ES6 has been out for a while now, and now I should covert all my React code to that. I also find out about requireJS, and Flux (design pattern), redux (but I need NodeJS to even get started). And a lot of other frameworks.

I'm just so overwhelmed by all of these, I don't know where to start or what to use, for example:

- should I be using requireJS or just learn ES6 import/export or should I be using nodeJS? Sometimes it is tough to even understand example from Git, their files are all over different folders.
- what other framework should I learn, AngularJS, backboneJS?

I have a Computer Science degree and just want to get into a junior web developer position, and I need a job. But I feel like new frameworks keep on coming, by the time I catch up, new ones will come out, how am I ever going to get into the field?

I'm in despair, will someone with knowledge please give me some direction? I really need advice and have no idea who or where to ask beside here.

Comment: This is the way it's always been, new stuff keep popping up, old stuff keeps disappearing, programming is something that evolves quickly, and you should be prepared for that, it's unlikely you'll find a job where you can just  keep on writing the same code for the next ten years. Most of these frameworks however, are just hype, and are completely uneccessary, you can build the exact same stuff without them, but they do generally make things easier once you've learnt how they work, and as it's all built on javascript, it's not that hard.

Comment: Going to vote to close this, but think the real answer here is to RELAX. Getting a job isn't defined by which framework/version of JS or anything like that is. Getting a job is being personable and knowing foundations.

Comment: Recommended reading on JavaScript Fatigue: https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/javascript-fatigue-48d4011b6fc4#.9yi5nif7b

Comment: Learn core JavaScript. Once you master that any JS framework should be pretty quickly to pick up. There isn't a "right" framework to learn. Each company uses different things and its constantly changing. So if you learn the foundation then you can always adapt quickly

Comment: Hi thanks for the advise so far. I understand it's ever changing, and I don't expect to use the same code for years. But for someone that just started there are so many material, I want to know how and what to learn in order to get started as a junior web developer. Where do a new developer start?

Comment: @erichardson30: So to get my foot in the door, the best way is to learn is to instead start projects using vanillaJS? and learn maybe one framework?

Comment: @user308553 getting a junior developer job is pretty easy imo. you just have to show interest and have some projects under your belt. maybe a website that you built that does something or a java project that queries a database for school. as long as you show up with some form of knowledge and ability to learn, 3 times out of 5 you will probably get a job offer.

Comment: @user308553 Yeah I would say that's a good place to start. Pick a framework you like or have interest in and build out an application with it. Doesn't have to be anything crazy. Just to help you understand the foundation and principles behind it. Then in an interview you can talk about javascript and that framework in decent detail. An employer will never expect you to know everything. They want to see that you can learn and adapt quickly

Comment: @user308553 well I do have those, I guess I just have to keep applying, it's just that seeing all these junior job positing that look for certain frameworks overwhelmed me a bit. Thanks

Comment: The Passionate Programmer gives some advice how to choose technologies and your future: https://pragprog.com/book/cfcar2/the-passionate-programmer . You may choose something popular and simple to start and later switch to something more advanced. With ES5 you can find job quickly today, and with ES6 tomorrow. Angular is for today. And Angular2 is for tomorrow. Invest with care and just do something.

Comment: (As interesting as this question is, it is very off-topic for Stack Overflow, and will close in due course. Please use Reddit for this in future - thanks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions specifically:

> ...now I should covert all my React code to that.

Just use new features as you become aware of them, no need to convert everything!

> I also find out about requireJS, and Flux (design pattern), redux (but
>   I need NodeJS to even get started). And a lot of other frameworks.

My advice is forget about requireJS, flux and redux( -take a look at mobx)... Get webpack/babel/react set up (there are template projects you can use as starting point) and you are good to go with es6 and learning cutting edge skills that will easily land you a job.  IMHO.

> should I be using requireJS or just learn ES6 import/export or should
>   I be using nodeJS.

Yes, just use es6 import, why not? You'll need node/npm installed as *many things* depend on them.

> what other framework should I learn, angularJS, backboneJS.

Nah, these are old hat now - continue with react as it is in demand right now. Look at mobx as an alternative to redux. Other libraries? Knockout is old, but good. RxJS is interesting. Learn about functional programming, protocols like HTTP and fundamentals that will distinguish you in an interview context. Make demos.

Comment: Hey Tom. Thanks for the useful info. Please allow me to ask one more. How do one keep up to date with new framework/lib? I mean I only learnt about redux cause I was browsing React section in stackoverflow, I never even heard of mobx until now. Thanks

Comment: @user308553 I find it quite useful to subscribe to a JavaScript newsletter like javascriptweekly.com it helps me keep up to date on what the cool kids are doing.

Comment: oh thanks Ill check that out, someone suggested echojs to me the other day too, but it isnt a newsletter like this one, thanks